# Angular UI-Calendar AddEvent doesn't work when $scope.events is populated through Factory

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar, angular-ui

As shown in this plunkr example, a new event can be added and displayed when the event is appended to $scope.events directly. However, if I update $scope.events through factory.events, the new event is not displayed on the calendar.

http://plnkr.co/edit/BkdzJJ?p=preview

This has to be something really simple that I'm missing, but I've been struggling with this issue for weeks now. Can you please help?

```
app = angular.module('myApp');

function CalendarCtrl ($scope, gDataService) {
var today = new Date();
var m = today.getMonth();
var y = today.getFullYear();
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();

$scope.events2 = [];  // This gets data through gDataService
$scope.events3 = [];  // This gets data directly from addEvent_direct method in this controller

// This is how I attempted to populate $scope.events2
$scope.$on('gDataUpdated', function(){
  //alert(gDataService.events2.length);

  $scope.events2 = gDataService.events2;
  alert('gDataService # of events =' + gDataService.events2.length.toString() 
  + '; $scope.events2 includes '+ $scope.events2.length.toString());
  // The alert message indicates $scope.events is properly updated based on 
  // gDataService.events2, but the new event doesn't appear on the calendar.
});

// This is how $scope.events3 is successfully populated
$scope.addEvent_direct = function() {

    var today = new Date();
    var m = today.getMonth();
    var y = today.getFullYear();
    var d = today.getDate();
    object = { title: 'Event directly added',
        start: new Date(y, m, 28),
        end: new Date(y, m, 29),
        className: ['openSesame']}
    $scope.events3.push(object);
}

// both events2 and events3 are included as eventSources
$scope.eventSources = [ $scope.events2 ,$scope.events3];

$scope.uiConfig = {
    fullCalendar: {
        height: 550,
        editable: false
    }
};
}
CalendarCtrl.$inject = [ '$scope','gDataService'];
```

// This is the factory that gets event2 data from another controller (ButtonCtrl)

```
app.factory("gDataService", function ($rootScope) {
var service = {};
service.events = [];
service.events2 = [];
service.added_event_short = {start: null, title: null};

service.addData = function(object) {

  this.events2.push(object);
  //alert(this.events2.length);
  $rootScope.$broadcast("gDataUpdated");
};

return service;
});
```

//This is a controller separated from CalendarCtrl in order to test how different controllers can share data through factory

```
app.controller('ButtonCtrl', function($scope,gDataService) {

  $scope.addEvent = function() {

    var today = new Date();
    var m = today.getMonth();
    var y = today.getFullYear();
    var d = today.getDate();
    object = { title: 'Open Sesame',
        start: new Date(y, m, 28),
        end: new Date(y, m, 29),
        className: ['openSesame']}

  gDataService.addData(object);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
  //$scope.events2 = gDataService.events2; //replace with below
  angular.forEach(gDataService.events2, function(event) {
    console.log(event);
    $scope.events2.push(event);
  });
```

The reason is, you use '$scope.events2' to bind the data in view, but you replace the js object with new data during update. Then the watch on previous object doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks. What is it about the new data that makes the watch not work? I guess I don't understand how the watch knows the data changed.

Comment: At first you bind data with calendar view with '$scope.eventSources = [ $scope.events2 ,$scope.events3];', then angularjs will watch the reference of '$scope.events2' to check the value change.  When you update events, you replace the the reference with new one '$scope.events2 = gDataService.events2' , then the previous reference still refers to previous data, and not changed. So you should use the same reference during binding. And when you update, you should update the data in previous object.

Comment: And you should notice the difference when you bind the model of object (like array and object) and primitive type (like number, string, boolean). I you bind the data of primitive type, it will bind by value, you can directly update the value and get updated in view. If you bind data of object type, it will bind by reference. If you update the reference, it will not update the data in view.