# refresh ng-repeat ng-class conditional following removal of element

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using bootstrap's offsets in my layout, and have a simple conditional that places the offset on every 5th element.

```
class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-5 ng-class:{'col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2' : !($index % 5)}"
```

I also made a directive that shows a little red box on hover, allowing a user to delete their element. Works fine, except that the layout won't refresh and the offsets get set on the wrong elements, making a big mess of the layout.

I tried doing scope.$apply(), but this didn't help. How can I accomplish this?

my html:

```
  <body  ng-controller="MyController">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div ng-repeat="image in images" 
           dg-deletable="" 
           class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-5 ng-class:{'col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2' : !($index % 5)}">
        <div class="imagebox">
          <div>{{image.name}}</div>
          <div class="imagecover"></div>
          <img width="140" src="{{image.file}}" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

inside my directive:

```
delete_btn.on('click', function(event) {
    scope.$apply(function() {  
        element.remove();
    });
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/2ADoSYwPuh46Zh5ylmjw?p=preview
(you'll need to view in fullpage mode)

Comment: ng-class could be  used as you used it here. !($index % 5) does not work. use ($index % 5)>0

Comment: thanks but no. It works fine until I remove the element. That isn't the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are right @dgig.  `!($index % 5)` works fine. The problem is that you should delete the image from the array too.
I have changed the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/d7CRevQLZmEhufeA9NJk?p=preview)
I think the code could be written better using angular. You can use angular directives to fire events and set the style-sheet.

```
delete_btn.on('click', function(event) {
        scope.$apply(function() {  
            angular.forEach(scope.images, function(img){
              if(img.name == attr.imagename){
                scope.images.splice(scope.images.indexOf(img),1);  
              }
            });
            element.remove();
        });
    });
```

I set the `imagename` as an attribute to be used in delete function.

```
<body  ng-controller="MyController">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div ng-repeat="image in images" dg-deletable="" imagename={{image.name}}  class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-5 ng-class:{'col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2' :  !($index % 5)}">
        <div class="imagebox">
          <div>{{image.name}}</div>
          <div class="imagecover"></div>
          <img width="140" src="{{image.file}}" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Ah great, your plunker works exactly as I am hoping to achieve. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

ng-class needs to be its own HTML attribute, like so

```
<body  ng-controller="MyController">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div ng-repeat="image in images" 
           dg-deletable="" 
           class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-5" ng-class="{'col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2' : !($index % 5)}">
        <div class="imagebox">
          <div>{{image.name}}</div>
          <div class="imagecover"></div>
          <img width="140" src="{{image.file}}" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: hm. I appreciate the help, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: I would look at the condition for your class assignment then and make sure it's reaching the value you think it should be

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem. It seems possible that I'm deleting the element but not changing the scope. I need to figure out how to do that. Thanks

Comment: Using your plunkr example, everything works fine once I change the condition from !($index % 5) to ($index % 5) > 1, this may not be the condition you want to match, but the elements where $index%5>1 update after you delete an element and the new element which equals 0 has the classes removed. This is the intended functionality and it's working correctly

Answer (score 0):

It is a very simple problem about data binding procily of angularjs, refer my another [answer and explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28402477/966698)

You just need to use obj.images to bind images data, but not using images directly.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but the plunker provided exhibits the same problem behavior. Removing one of the images causes the offset to fall apart.